# When does using a Shield help?

Tags: mistborn

Going over the rule about Conflict regarding Action/Defense Dice, it's not clear when Shields (which grant Defense Dice against physical attacks) are useful.

Do you always roll Shield Dice when you can make a Defense Pool against a physical attack? Do you only get the Dice when you use your Action to Defend and/or when you use your Action for something that doesn't cause you to gain Action Dice nor Defense Dice (but are physically attacked during that round)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You get Shield di(c)e each time you roll Defense against a physical attack

Alex Flagg, cited for design of the Game System and Product Development, [indicated](https://www.crafty-games.com/forum/index.php?topic=6597.msg117714#msg117714) that you add shield dice to each instance of Defending against a physical attack.

> They apply to every defensive roll - so if you have a large shield, you automatically gain 2 dice every time you defend.